# Structuring Visual Studio Solution to Run Tests inside Library Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

I am working with Visual Studio 2022, and have been creating my own library in C++. When I first started I decided to make a second project in my solution to simulate how someone would use the library. This second project also became where I started adding my tests for my library, and to keep the github page clean I only publish the library project. This resulted in my tests not actually being in the github repository. This is how my solution is currently structured:

```
Library Solution
\myLibrary
    \src
        ...Other files
        library.cpp
\main
    \src
        \tests
            test.cpp
        \main.cpp
```

I want to finally fix this and actually have my Google tests in the library project, so my tests are public on GitHub. I want my library to be structured more like:

```
Library Solution
\myLibrary
    \src
        ...Other files
        library.cpp
    \tests
        test.cpp
\main
    \src
        \main.cpp
```

I have tried to switch the startup project from the main project to the library project, but I get an error saying that "...Library Solution.lib is not a valid Win32 application". I have tried to find other solutions online, but most tutorials reconmend creating a second project with the google tests template. This would not solve my issue *(as I would just be adding another project to the solution).

TLDR, how can I run google tests in a library project on Visual Studio?

Comment: You probably should expand on "but most tutorials reconmend creating a second project with the google tests template. *This would not solve my issue.*". It's obvious that you can't run library (as it is "not a valid Win32 application"... hard to argue with VS there) but it is unclear why you can't have exe for tests in the same solution.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The reason I said it would not solve my issue, was because I would just be adding another project to the solution, and thus having the test code separate from the library project. I know it would work, but I would like for the tests to be present in the library so other people could use them. When looking at online resources like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398445/directory-structure-for-a-c-library it seems possible to have my tests structured like I said in the question. I just can't figure out how to run it from there.

Comment: lib cannot be executed.  There is `right click project ->run Test` option. But  I'm afraid google test doesn't support running tests directly in a DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You cannot. A library is a library, a test project using that library is an executable. You cannot execute libraries.

As other commenters wrote, the recommended way would be to publish a solution which contains a separate project for the library and one for the tests for that library. Take a look at the GoogleTest project as an example.